# I was trying to create a dropdown filter for PowerPoint charts

Tags: excel, vba, filter, charts, powerpoint

[image: 2]

[image: 1]

I was trying to create a dropdown filter for PowerPoint charts( i have  4 charts). when i select the value from list(horizontal x axis values), it should update the chart till that value.

i was working with a code using combo box, added values in it.
had a code which specifies Combo box name, chart name, series(inside chart), and range of values (inside the built in excel sheet) of chart.

but was not getting output, when i execute

```vb
 Sub UpdateChart()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim selectedValue As String
    
    ' Set the slide that contains the chart
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    
    ' Set the shape name of the ComboBox (change "ComboBox1" to your ComboBox name)
    Set shp = sld.Shapes("ComboBox1")
    
    ' Get the selected value from the ComboBox
    selectedValue = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value
    
    ' Set the name of the chart data series (change "Series 1" to the appropriate name)
    Dim seriesName As String
    seriesName = "Series 1"
    
    ' Set the data range for the chart (change "A2:A10" to the appropriate range)
    Dim dataRange As String
    dataRange = "A2:A10"
    
    ' Loop through the chart data points and update the series values based on the selected value
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To sld.Shapes.Count
        If sld.Shapes(i).HasChart Then
            Dim cht As Chart
            Set cht = sld.Shapes(i).Chart
            cht.SeriesCollection(seriesName).Values = Evaluate("IF(" & dataRange & "=""" & selectedValue & """," & dataRange & ", NA())")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

will be great to have some help..

thanks.

Comment: `Evaluate` is a method of Excel application. You can't use it in PowerPoint VBA.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome, is there any method for PowerPoint use

Comment: I am not sure what's your goal. Would you mind upload a screenshot to show the detail?

Comment: I've added the image link, so you can see the charts have same horizontal values, i want to update chart, when i select the horizontal value in dropdown till (for example 3) & IT UPDATES ALL CHARTS TILL VALUE 3

Answer (score 0):

Linked Excel charts in PowerPoint have limitations. Chart data series cannot be restored through VBA once modified. For example, if `3` is selected in the combobox by user, the chart series can be filtered to show only the first 3 points with `SeriesCollection().Values`. However, there is no way to restore the original full data series completely through PowerPoint VBA if `5` is the next selection. (Please correct me if there is a better approach I am missing.)

A workaround is to create the dynamic chart directly in Excel. The selection from the PowerPoint combobox can be passed to Excel to filter the chart data. This allows full control of chart.

---

`Chart.xlsx` keeps data source. Excel file and PowerPoint file are stored in `the same directory`.

**STEP1**: Define name (dynamic refers)

| Name | Refers To |
| --- | --- |
| Sheet1!XCate | =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,,,Sheet1!$F$1,1) |
| Sheet1!YSeri1 | =OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2,,,Sheet1!$F$1,1) |
| Sheet1!YSeri2 | =OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$2,,,Sheet1!$F$1,1) |

**STEP2**: Update Chart series formula

| Name | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| Series 1 | =SERIES(Sheet1!$B$1,Sheet1!XCate,Sheet1!YSeri1,1) |
| Series 2 | =SERIES(Sheet1!$C$1,Sheet1!XCate,Sheet1!YSeri2,2) |

**STEP3**: Copy chart and paste it into slide as linked object

**STEP4**: Add PowerPoint VBA code

---

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
    If ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then Call AddItem
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim xlApp As Object, xlWK As Object, xlSht
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlWK = xlApp.workbooks("Chart.xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If xlWK Is Nothing Then
        Set xlWK = xlApp.workbooks.Open(ActivePresentation.Path & "\Chart.xlsx")
    End If
    Set xlSht = xlWK.activesheet
    xlSht.Range("F1").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    xlWK.Save
    xlWK.Close
    Call RefreshChart
End Sub

'Refresh chart on slide
Sub RefreshChart()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim wk
    For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        If shp.HasChart Then
            Set cht = shp.Chart
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wk = cht.ChartData.Workbook
            On Error GoTo 0
            cht.Refresh
        End If
    Next
End Sub

' Initial ComboBox, called by GotFocus
Sub AddItem()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 5
        ComboBox1.AddItem CStr(i)
    Next
    Call RefreshChart
End Sub
```

---

**Excel sample data and chart**

[image: 1]

**PowerPoint dynamic chart**

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks for Workaround. But Unfortunately i was not able to add Chart series formula in my version of excel, Hope this solution works for others.